# Display User Relationship request dialog on content profile page

Tags: 6, users, forms

I need to create an 'add friend' link programatically.

```
       $content .= '<li>' . l('<span class="icon"></span>Add to your friends', 'relationship/' . $tid . '/request/1?destination=user/' . $tid, array('html' => true, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'add`-friend')));
```

It leads me to another page with confirmation form for the invitation.

Could anybody tell me how (if possible) I can display this confirmation form in dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all because laziness. It's so easy to do.

I need to add this link with dialog on content profile page.

All to do is:

- add js to content profile page:

  ```
      if ($variables['node']->type == 'profile') {  
          drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'user_relationships_ui') .'/user_relationships_ui.js');
      }
  ```
- add class to request relationship link:

> user_relationships_popup_link

Answer (score 1):

I've created Add as friend likes in a project once doing this:

```
l(t('Add as friend'), 'relationship/' . $account->uid . '/request');
```

It served me fine, but I'm not sure if you want something different.